# Makefile only creating first file

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a Makefile as follows:

```
work/step1.tab: temp.tab hcp_raw_data_sample.tab
    command

work/step2.tab: work/step1.tab
    command
```

I have `temp.tab` and `hcp_raw_data_sample.tab` in the home directory and want `step1.tab` and `step2.tab` to be created in the `work` directory. However, it is only `step1.tab` which gets created; `step2.tab` does not. What do I do?

Comment: How are you running `make`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `make` it builds the first target listed in the makefile, in this case `work/step1.tab`. It doesn't see any reason to build step2.tab because it had everything it needed to build step1, which was the default target.

To have it build both, move `work/step2.tab` above `work/step1.tab`. This makes `work/step2.tab` the default target.

This way it will see that it needs to build `work/step1.tab` before it can build `work/step2.tab`, so it will do so, and then it will build `work/step2.tab`.

Answer (score 1):

Make executes only the first target. Usually you create a target `all` that creates all sub-targets you want. If you place `all` as the first target, that will be built if you call `make`.